# Trouble chaining option and struct field using iterator interface

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make the following code work:

```
struct IntHolder {
    ints: Vec<i32>,
}

impl IntHolder {
    fn special_int(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        return None;
    }
    fn all_ints(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&i32> {
        return self.special_int().iter().chain(self.ints.iter());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tst = IntHolder{ints: vec![0, 1, 2]};
    for o in tst.all_ints() {
        println!("{}", o)
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
   |
10 |         return self.special_int().iter().chain(self.ints.iter());
   |                ------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                |
   |                returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                temporary value created here
```

Oddly enough, if I change the function call to just inline `None` instead of calling the function that returns an option, it works:

```
struct IntHolder {
    ints: Vec<i32>,
}

impl IntHolder {
    fn special_int(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        return None;
    }
    fn all_ints(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&i32> {
        return None.iter().chain(self.ints.iter());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tst = IntHolder{ints: vec![0, 1, 2]};
    for o in tst.all_ints() {
        println!("{}", o)
    }
}
```

---

Does anyone know how to make this work, or why it only seems to break when I call a function to generate the option?

(This is toy code to illustrate the problem I'm having.  In my actual code, I have a struct which holds a vector of objects, and also sometimes has a special object that can be computed from the other fields.  I want to return an iterator that iterates over the special object if it can be computed, and then iterates over all the objects in the vector.  I'd also like to avoid having to do heap allocations if I can.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `iter` takes a reference to the value rather than consuming it, returning an iterator that references a value that belongs to the function.

Try using `into_iter()` instead:

```
return self.special_int().into_iter().chain(self.ints.iter());
```

Comment: Thanks!  This almost works, but the problem is that `into_iter()` gives me an iterator over `i32` instead of `&i32`.  I can change the signature to return an iterator over `i32` and write `self.special_int().into_iter().chain(self.ints.iter().copied())`, but I'd prefer to return an iterator over references for the code I'm actually trying to write.  Is there something like `into_iter` which will give me an iterator over references instead?